# Ion-select with dynamic data and dynamic options

Tags: typescript, ionic3

i am developing `Hybrid` app using `ionic-3`. i want to display dynamic question and its dynamic answer options. i tried it from below code and it will display question and its optional answer but i can't select all question's answer(when i select second question's answer first question's answer become empty because of it's value is same in all question).please help me.

```
<div *ngFor="let x of question_list">
<div class="amount">{{x.question}}</div>
<ion-item class="select_q">
  <ion-label>Answer</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="form.ans">
    <div *ngFor="let y of x.ans; let i = index">
    <ion-option  value="{{y}}">{{y}}</ion-option>
  </div>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously it will happen if you will use the same ngModel for all selects. What is your exact requirement?

Comment: i want to display multiple question and it's  optional select answer from single jsondata. [jsondata_image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kt9aDuUTAqAs7XkjLRdn5mCIHFGE3wTe/view)

Comment: Yeah I understood that. I mean what do you want to do after that with the values selected by the user?

Comment: After that with the values selected by the user i want to pass all questions and its answer to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new property "selected" in your JSON array data and use that in the ngModel like this.

home.component.ts

```
this.question_list.forEach((q)=>{
  q["selected"] = ""
})
```

home.component.html

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="x.selected">
<div *ngFor="let y of x.ans; let i = index">
    <ion-option  value="{{y}}">{{y}}</ion-option>
</div>
</ion-select>
```

I made a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OadJcciM40AT0rmSibjN?p=preview) doing just that. Let me know if that's what you want.
PS. I added a button to print out the selected values. You can change it as per your requirement.

Comment: yes,that's exactly i want to do. its works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Working perfect for me**

**my json data**

```
"data": [
    "6 Years Insurance Plan",
    "10 Years Insurance Plan",
    "20 Years Insurance Plan",
    "Life Time Insurance Plan",
    "Medical Plan"
]
```

**Html file**

```
<ion-item class="cus-select">
    <ion-select (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let friend of myFriendsArray; let i = index" 
                                [value]="friend.$value">
                                    {{friend.fullName}}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**in .ts file**

```
selectedFriendsArray = [];
allplansArray = [];
myFriendsArray = [];
planobject: any;

public loadingController: LoadingController) {
    this.mainurl = global.MAIN_URL;
    this.selectedplan = 0;
}

//change listner
onSelectChange(selectedValue: Number) {
    this.selectedplan = selectedValue;
    console.log('Selected', selectedValue);
    console.log('Change listner SelectedPlan', this.selectedplan);
}
```

also in .ts parsing

```
this.http.post(this.mainurl + "plans", postData, requestOptions)
        .subscribe(data => {
    this.hideProgressBar();

    console.log(data['_body']);
    var response = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    this.allplans = response.data;
    console.log("all plans" + this.allplans);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.allplans.length; i++) {
        this.planobject = { $value: i + 1, fullName: this.allplans[i] };
        this.myFriendsArray.push(this.planobject);
    }
    console.log(this.myFriendsArray);

}, error => {
    this.hideProgressBar();
    console.log(error);
    this.showAlertMessage('Server Error please try');
});
```